I am trying to understand the definition of qualified covered calls and larger straddles
Below is a quote from IRS Pub 550:
Qualified covered call options and optioned stock.
A straddle is not subject to the loss deferral rules for straddles if both of the following are true.

All the offsetting positions consist of one or more
qualified covered call options and the stock to be purchased from you under the options.
The straddle is not part of a larger straddle

What is the purpose of the line I marked 2? Could somebody give me an example of a case where a qualified covered call is subject to the loss deferral rules because it is part off a larger straddle?


I am trying to understand the definition of qualified covered calls
and larger straddles

Good luck.
This is a highly technical question that even someone who is both a lawyer and CPA and has an LLM in tax will struggle with (and I am a mere lawyer who has lots of tax experience and some undergraduate accounting classes), and which the IRS has struggled with. But the answer at least points towards the most relevant resources.
The relevant tax code section is 26 U.S.C. § 1092 (the link has the full text of the statute and links to the relevant regulations and authorities), although it interplays heavily with other sections of the tax code, especially 26 U.S.C. § 1256.
The IRS recognizes that clarity in this area is tricky. It has abandoned proposals to issue new regulations related to this section in 1998, 2001, and 2013, after finding its proposed regulations were inadequate to improve the clarity of the law after receiving public comment each time. Congress has stepped in with its own technical fixes of the original 1997 law in 1999, 2000, 2004, 2005, 2007 and 2018, which have sometimes made the statute more rather than less difficult to understand.
The term "staddle" has a long a technical definition at 26 U.S.C. § 1092(c):

Straddle defined. For purposes of this section--
(1) In general. The term "straddle" means offsetting positions with
respect to personal property.
(2) Offsetting positions.
(A) In general. A taxpayer holds offsetting positions with respect to
personal property if there is a substantial diminution of the
taxpayer's risk of loss from holding any position with respect to
personal property by reason of his holding 1 or more other positions
with respect to personal property (whether or not of the same kind).
(B) Special rule for identified straddles. In the case of any position
which is not part of an identified straddle (within the meaning of
subsection (a)(2)(B)), such position shall not be treated as
offsetting with respect to any position which is part of an identified
straddle.
(3) Presumption.
(A) In general. For purposes of paragraph (2), 2 or more positions
shall be presumed to be offsetting if--
(i) the positions are in the same personal property (whether
established in such property or a contract for such property),
(ii) the positions are in the same personal property, even though such
property may be in a substantially altered form,
(iii) the positions are in debt instruments of a similar maturity or
other debt instruments described in regulations prescribed by the
Secretary,
(iv) the positions are sold or marketed as offsetting positions
(whether or not such positions are called a straddle, spread,
butterfly, or any similar name),
(v) the aggregate margin requirement for such positions is lower than
the sum of the margin requirements for each such position (if held
separately), or
(vi) there are such other factors (or satisfaction of subjective or
objective tests) as the Secretary may by regulations prescribe as
indicating that such positions are offsetting.
For purposes of the preceding sentence, 2 or more positions shall be
treated as described in clause (i), (ii), (iii), or (vi) only if the
value of 1 or more of such positions ordinarily varies inversely with
the value of 1 or more other such positions.
(B) Presumption may be rebutted. Any presumption established pursuant
to subparagraph (A) may be rebutted.
(4) Exception for certain straddles consisting of qualified covered
call options and the optioned stock.
(A) In general. If--
(i) all the offsetting positions making up any straddle consist of 1
or more qualified covered call options and the stock to be purchased
from the taxpayer under such options, and
(ii) such straddle is not part of a larger straddle,
such straddle shall not be treated as a straddle for purposes of this
section and section 263(g).
(B) Qualified covered call option defined. For purposes of
subparagraph (A), the term "qualified covered call option" means any
option granted by the taxpayer to purchase stock held by the taxpayer
(or stock acquired by the taxpayer in connection with the granting of
the option) but only if--
(i) such option is traded on a national securities exchange which is
registered with the Securities and Exchange Commission or other market
which the Secretary determines has rules adequate to carry out the
purposes of this paragraph,
(ii) such option is granted more than 30 days before the day on which
the option expires,
(iii) such option is not a deep-in-the-money option,
(iv) such option is not granted by an options dealer (within the
meaning of section 1256(g)(8)) in connection with his activity of
dealing in options, and
(v) gain or loss with respect to such option is not ordinary income or
loss.
(C) Deep-in-the-money option. For purposes of subparagraph (B), the
term "deep-in-the-money option" means an option having a strike price
lower than the lowest qualified bench mark.
(D) Lowest qualified bench mark.
(i) In general. Except as otherwise provided in this subparagraph, for
purposes of subparagraph (C), the term "lowest qualified bench mark"
means the highest available strike price which is less than the
applicable stock price.
(ii) Special rule where option is for period more than 90 days and
strike price exceeds $50. In the case of an option--
(I) which is granted more than 90 days before the date on which such
option expires, and
(II) with respect to which the strike price is more than $50,
the lowest qualified bench mark is the second highest available strike
price which is less than the applicable stock price.
(iii) 85 percent rule where applicable stock price $25 or less. If--
(I) the applicable stock price is $25 or less, and
(II) but for this clause, the lowest qualified bench mark would be
less than 85 percent of the applicable stock price,
the lowest qualified bench mark shall be treated as equal to 85
percent of the applicable stock price.
(iv) Limitation where applicable stock price $150 or less. If--
(I) the applicable stock price is $150 or less, and
(II) but for this clause, the lowest qualified bench mark would be
less than the applicable stock price reduced by $10,
the lowest qualified bench mark shall be treated as equal to the
applicable stock price reduced by $10.
(E) Special year-end rule. Subparagraph (A) shall not apply to any
straddle for purposes of section 1092(a) if--
(i) the qualified covered call options referred to in such
subparagraph are closed or the stock is disposed of at a loss during
any taxable year,
(ii) gain on disposition of the stock to be purchased from the
taxpayer under such options or gains on such options are includible in
gross income for a later taxable year, and
(iii) such stock or option was not held by the taxpayer for 30 days or
more after the closing of such options or the disposition of such
stock.
For purposes of the preceding sentence, the rules of paragraphs (3)
and (4) of section 246(c) shall apply in determining the period for
which the taxpayer holds the stock.
(F) Strike price. For purposes of this paragraph, the term "strike
price" means the price at which the option is exercisable.
(G) Applicable stock price. For purposes of subparagraph (D), the term
"applicable stock price" means, with respect to any stock for which an
option has been granted--
(i) the closing price of such stock on the most recent day on which
such stock was traded before the date on which such option was
granted, or
(ii) the opening price of such stock on the day on which such option
was granted, but only if such price is greater than 110 percent of the
price determined under clause (i).
(H) Regulations. The Secretary shall prescribe such regulations as may
be necessary or appropriate to carry out the purposes of this
paragraph. Such regulations may include modifications to the
provisions of this paragraph which are appropriate to take account of
changes in the practices of option exchanges or to prevent the use of
options for tax avoidance purposes.

Treasury Regulation § 1.1092(c)-1 to 1.092(c)-4 purport to clarify this definition. The only one that is really relevant to this question if Treas. Reg. § 1.1092(c)-1 (qualified cover calls) which states:

(a) In general. Section 1092(c) defines a straddle as offsetting
positions with respect to personal property. Under section
1092(d)(3)(B)(i)(I), stock is personal property if the stock is part
of a straddle that involves an option on that stock or substantially
identical stock or securities. Under section 1092(c)(4), however,
writing a qualified covered call option and owning the optioned stock
is not treated as a straddle under section 1092 if certain conditions,
described in section 1092(c)(4)(B), are satisfied. Section
1092(c)(4)(H) authorizes the Secretary to modify these conditions to
carry out the purposes of section 1092(c)(4) in light of changes in
the marketplace.
(b) Term limitation--
(1) General rule. Except as provided in paragraph (b)(2) of this
section, an option is not a qualified covered call unless it is
granted not more than 12 months before the day on which the option
expires or satisfies term limitation and qualified benchmark
requirements established by the Commissioner in guidance published in
the Internal Revenue Bulletin (see §601.601(d)(2)(ii)(b) of this
chapter).
(2) Special benchmark rule for an option granted not more than 33
months before the day on which the option expires--
(i) In general. The 12-month limitation described in paragraph (b)(1)
of this section is extended to 33 months provided the lowest qualified
benchmark is determined using the adjusted applicable stock price, as
defined in §1.1092(c)-4(e).
(ii) Examples. The following examples illustrate the rules set out in
paragraph (b)(2)(i) of this section:
Example 1. Taxpayer owns stock in Corporation X. Taxpayer writes an
equity option with standardized terms on Corporation X stock through a
national securities exchange with a term of 21 months. The applicable
stock price for Corporation X stock is $100. The bench marks for a
21-month equity option with standardized terms with an applicable
stock price of $100 will be based upon the adjusted applicable stock
price. Using the table at § 1.1092(c)-4(e), the applicable stock price
of $100 is multiplied by the adjustment factor 1.12, resulting in an
adjusted applicable stock price of $112. Using the bench marks for an
equity option with standardized terms with an adjusted applicable
stock price of $112, the highest available strike price less than the
adjusted applicable stock price is $110, and the second highest strike
price less than the adjusted applicable stock price is $105.
Therefore, a 21-month equity call option with standardized terms on
Corporation X stock will not be deep in the money if the strike price
is not less than $105.
Example 2. Taxpayer owns stock in Corporation Y. Taxpayer writes an
equity option with standardized terms on Corporation Y stock through a
national securities exchange with a term of 21 months. The applicable
stock price for Corporation Y stock is $13.25. The bench marks for a
21-month equity option with standardized terms with an applicable
stock price of $13.25 will be based upon the adjusted applicable stock
price. Using the table at §1.1092(c)-4(e), the applicable stock price
of $13.25 is multiplied by the adjustment factor 1.12, resulting in an
adjusted applicable stock price of $14.84. Using the bench marks for
an equity option with standardized terms with an adjusted applicable
stock price of $14.84, the highest available strike price less than
the adjusted applicable stock price is $12.50. However, under section
1092(c)(4)(D), the lowest qualified bench mark can be no lower than
85% of the applicable stock price, which for Corporation Y stock is
$12.61 (85% of the adjusted applicable stock price of $14.84). Thus,
because the highest available strike price less than the adjusted
applicable stock price for an equity option with standardized terms is
lower than the lowest qualified bench mark under section
1092(c)(4)(D), the lowest strike price at which a qualified covered
call option can be written is the next higher strike price, or $15.00.
Therefore, a 21-month equity call option with standardized terms on
Corporation Y stock will not be deep in the money if the strike price
is not less than $15.
(c) Effective date. This section applies to qualified covered call
options entered into on or after July 29, 2002.
[Added by T.D. 8990, 67 FR 20896-20901, Apr. 29, 2002.]

Essentially all fourteen of the cases interpreting the statute involve "sham" straddles in gold, silver, oil, or unspecified commodities, that were used to take losses that had no economic substance, in simpler fact patterns.
Temporary Treasury Regulations § 1.1092(b)-1T to § 1.1092(b)-5T explore "mixed straddles" and "straddle by straddle identification" which could be relevant.
A 2016 article by a CPA-attorney attempts to make sense of it. He notes that:

Under IRC section 1092(a)(2)(B), to establish an identified straddle,
the straddle—which must not be part of a larger straddle—must be
identified on the taxpayer’s books and records by the close of the day
on which it is established. As long as the taxpayers make a timely
identification and apply a consistent methodology, the IRS has
accepted the identifications as valid.

Probably the most definitive treatment of the question is found in Revenue Ruling 2002-66 which states in the pertinent part:

Even if this requirement is satisfied, however, clause (ii) precludes
the exemption from applying if the taxpayer holds at least one other
position (i.e., a position other than qualified covered call options
and the stock to be purchased thereunder) that, when considered
together with the stock and qualified covered call options described
in clause (i), creates a larger straddle.
Neither the statutory language nor the legislative history of §
1092(c)(4) defines the term "part of a larger straddle."  Section
1092(a)(2)(B)(iii) uses the same phrase in the definition of an
identified straddle but does not define the term "larger straddle.@"
The legislative history to § 1092(a)(2)(B)(iii) also does not define
the term but does state that A[i]n addition, an identified straddle
cannot constitute part of a larger straddle (for example, a
butterfly). S. Rep. No. 144, 97th Cong., 1st Sess. 148 (1981), 1981-2
C.B. 412, 471.  An example of a "butterfly" is a commodity straddle
consisting of a 5 unit short position expiring in May 2002, a 10 unit
long position expiring in June 2002, and a 5 unit short position
expiring in July 2002.  The relationship among the three positions in
a butterfly is explained in Leslie v. Commissioner , T.C. Memo
1996-86, aff=d , 146 F.3d 643 (9th Cir. 1998), cert. denied , 525 U.S.
1071 (1999):
The center position or body of a butterfly spread is twice as large as either wing, and the time periods for the delivery of the commodity
from the first wing to the body and from the body to the second wing
are equal.  Essentially, a butterfly spread creates two spreads, one
bullish and one bearish.  Thus, a butterfly spread presents less
chance of either an adverse or a favorable spread movement and is,
therefore, less likely to result in a different loss or gain than an
ordinary straddle.
The 1981 legislative history to § 1092(a)(2)(B)(iii), while not
directly applicable to § 1092(c)(4), supports the treatment of a
qualified covered call option as being "part of a larger straddle" if
the taxpayer holds one or more additional positions that substantially
diminish the risk of holding the equity by itself and the risk of the
combination of holding the equity and writing the qualified covered
call option.
The legislative history of the qualified covered call option exception
to § 1092 straddle treatment does not clarify the meaning of the
phrase "larger straddle" but does discuss considerations underlying
the decision to create the exemption.  The report of the House
Committee on Ways and Means contains this explanation:
One widely used investment strategy that would be affected by the extension of the straddle rules to stock options and stock involves
writing call options on stock owned by the taxpayer.  The committee
believes that it may be appropriate to exempt these transactions where
they are undertaken primarily to enhance the taxpayer's investment
return on the stock and not to reduce the taxpayer's risk of loss on
the stock.
H.R. Rep. No. 432, 98th Cong., 2d Sess. 1266 (1984).
In the three situations described above, the presence of a purchased
put substantially reduces the taxpayer's risk of loss with respect to
the stock, and also reduces any potential for enhancing the taxpayer's
investment return through premium income.  In each of the three
situations, the put option protects against a decrease in the value of
the stock below the exercise price of the put option and also reduces
the impact of changes in the value of the stock through the inverse
relationship between the value of the stock and the value of the put
option.  Both factors substantially diminish the risk of loss with
respect to the holding of the stock by itself and the risk of loss
with respect to the combination of the stock and the written qualified
covered call option.  In addition, when the owner of the stock
acquires the put, the amount of the premium received from the call
option is offset, in whole or in part, by the amount of the premium
paid for the put option, thus reducing any potential enhancement of
investment return on the stock resulting from the receipt of the call
option premium.  In effect, when the writer of the call option
purchases the put, the writer gives up potential enhancement of return
on investment to acquire additional risk protection.  Accordingly, in
each of the three situations described above, the presence of the
purchased put causes the stock and the qualified covered call option
to constitute part of a larger straddle within the meaning of §
1092(c)(4)(A).
HOLDINGS
Situation 1.  All of the positions in X stock are treated as part of a
larger straddle.  Section 1092(c)(4) does not apply to any of the
positions in X stock.
Situation 2.  All of the positions in Y stock are part of a larger
straddle beginning on September 6, 2002.  Section 1092(c)(4) does not
apply to any of the positions in Y stock beginning on that date.
Situation 3.  Prior to December 2, 2002, the combination of the
qualified covered call option and the underlying shares are not
treated as a straddle for purposes of §§ 1092 and 263(g).  However,
beginning on December 2, 2002, all of the positions in Z stock are
part of a larger straddle, and § 1092(c)(4), therefore, does not apply
to any of the positions in Z that date.

To understand the holdings, you'll have to read the whole thing at the link.
This admittedly, isn't an "explain it to a 5th grader" answer, but it does provide resources that point someone interested and knowledgable about the concepts involved in the right direction.

Thanks for a fine response. I think we agree that a covered call plus a long put position  on the stock results in a straddle with negative tax consequences for the investor.

What I am wondering about is a covered call plus a short put position. I  am thinking  that may  or may not  be one big straddle depending  on the  strike price of the puts and the calls. It is my belief that if an investor sells a covered call on the  XYZ stock  and then sells a put  on the  XYZ stock with  the same strike price then we have one big straddle. If the put is sold with a strike price significantly  below the  strike price of the call then  we do not have one big straddle. Do you agree?

@Bob I don't have the bandwidth in my head to analyze that issue right now. I'd probably need to take time to draw a diagram with references to the relevant part of the Revenue Ruling after re-reading it several times.
